# Sealing a small crack in poured concrete foundation

Tags: concrete, foundation, crack

I have a small crack in my foundation that started seeping water when there was ice on the ground.  The water is flowing along the foundation under my fireplace bump out.  The cause of the problem will be fixed in the spring when I put in a new concrete patio, but I want to seal the crack in the basement wall to prevent future seeping.  Would a product like [this](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1v/R-100653148/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053) be appropriate?  Is there a better recommendation?  The crack is fairly small less than 1/8" in width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An 1/8 inch crack that is weeping water is a fairly serious fault. Wondering, is the crack displaced or flat?  Regardless, any crack that allows water to seep through means the crack if through the entire wall. Normally I would recommend chiseling a "key" or an inverted "V" into the concrete and patching it with expanding hydrolic cement and coating the crack with a waterproofing rated for up to 4 PSI.  I personally have never used the product you linked to.  What is important is that bonds soundly. I would think it might be worth a try since you intend to do a better fix from the exterior in the spring. Remember, a simple concrete pad ove the area will not fix your problem, the leak is ground water, not a little ice melting on the top of the ground.

Comment: I talked to a few other people and decided to have it looked at by a professional to make sure it is done right.  I got a recommendation for a company that uses injected epoxy.  They charge $65 per linear foot.

Comment: I guess if the epoxy fix is warranted for life, it would be worth the $$$